# Is there a way to find a document matching two different populates and get his document in findOne()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm using mongoose with the combo mongoDb/nodejs. I would like to *findOne()* a doc with some conditions.

There is my **Schema** :

```
var prognosticSchema = new Schema({
    userRef : { type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'users'},
    matchRef : { type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'match'},
    ...
});
```

Model schema **'users'** contain a String *'email'* and model **'match'** contain a Number *'id_match'* like this:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    email: String,
    ...
});
```

then

```
var matchSchema = new Schema({
    id_match: {type: Number, min: 1, max: 51},
    ...
});
```

My goal is to *findOne()* one doc which contains an **id_match** = *id_match* and an **email** = *req.headers['x-key']*.

I tried this:

```
var prognoSchema = require('../db_schema/prognostic'); // require prognostics
require('../db_schema/match'); // require match to be able to populate

var prognoQuery = prognoSchema.find()
    .populate({path: 'userRef', // populate userRef
    match : {
        'email' : req.headers['x-key'] // populate where email match with email in headers of request (I'm using Express as node module)
    },
    select : 'email pseudo'
    });

    prognoQuery.findOne() // search for only one doc
        .populate({path: 'matchRef', // populate match
        match: {
            'id_match': id_match // populate match where id_match is correct
        }})
        .exec(function(err, data) {
             ... // Return of value as response ...
        }
```

When I run this code and try to get the right document knowing that there much of other *prognosticSchema* with such others *users* and *match* in my dataBase, i'll get **userRef** at null and correct **matchRef** in my data document.

In my dataBase, there is others *users* and others *id_match* but I would like to get the right document in *findOne()* helped by this two objectId in my Schema.

Is there a way to *findOne()* a document matching two different **populates** and get his document in *findOne()* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can include "both" `populate` expressions in the same query, but of course since you actually want to "match" on the properties contained in "referenced" collections this does mean that the actual data returned from the "parent" would need to look at "all parents" first in order to populate the data:

```js
prognoSchema.find()
  .populate([
    { 
      "path": "userRef",
      "match": { "email": req.headers['x-key'] }
    },
    { 
      "path": "matchRef",
      "match": { "id_match": id_match }
    }
  ]).exec(function(err,data) {
      /* 
          data contains the whole collection since there was no
          condition there. But populated references that did not
          match are now null. So .filter() them:
      */
      data = data.filter(function(doc) {
          return ( doc.userRef != null && doc.matchRef != null );
      });

      // data now contains only those item(s) that matched
  })
```

That is not ideal, but it's just how using "referenced" data works.

A better approach would be to search the other collections "indiviually" for there single match, and then supply the found `_id` values to the "parent" collection. A little help from [`async.parallel`](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) here to facilitate waiting on the results of the other queries before executing on the parent with the matched values. Can be done in various ways, but this looks relatively clean:

```js
async.parallel(
    {
        "userRef": function(callback) {
            User.findOne({ "email": req.headers['x-key'] },callback);
        },
        "id_match": function(callback) {
            Match.findOne({ "id_match": id_match },callback);
        }
    },
    function(err,result) {
        prognoSchema.findOne({
            "userRef": result.userRef._id,
            "matchRef": result.id_match._id
        }).populate([
          { "path": "userRef", "match": { "email": req.headers['x-key'] } },
          { "path": "matchRef", "match": { "id_match": id_match } }
        ]).exec(function(err,progno) {
            // Matched and populated data only
        })
    }
)
```

As an alternate, in modern MongoDB releases from 3.2 and onwards you could use the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation operator instead:

```js
prognoSchema.aggregate(
    [
        // $lookup the userRef data
        { "$lookup": {
            "from": "users",
            "localField": "userRef",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "userRef"
        }},
        // target is an array always so $unwind
        { "$unwind": "$userRef" },
        // Then filter out anything that does not match
        { "$match": {
            "userRef.email": req.headers['x-key']
        }},
        // $lookup the matchRef data
        { "$lookup": {
            "from": "matches",
            "localField": "matchRef",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "matchRef"
        }},
        // target is an array always so $unwind
        { "$unwind": "$matchRef" },
        // Then filter out anything that does not match
        { "$match": {
            "matchRef.id_match": id_match
        }}
    ],
    function(err,prognos) {

    }
)
```

But again similarly ugly since the "source" is still selecting everything and you are only gradually filtering out results after each [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) operation.

The basic premise here is *"MongoDB does not **'really'** perform joins"*, and neither is `.populate()` a "JOIN", but just additional queries on the related collections. Since this is "not" a "join" there is no way to filter out the "parent" until the actual related data is retrieved. Even if it's done on the "server" via [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) rather than on the "client" via `.populate()`

So if you "must" query this way, it's generally better to query the other collections for results "first" and then match the "parent" based on the matching `_id` property values as references.

But the other case here is that you "should" consider "embedding" the data instead, where it is your intent to "query" on those properties. **Only** when that data resides in the "single collection" is is possible for MongoDB to query and match those conditions with a single query and a performant operation.

Comment: I already use async in my API, I should use async.parallel to get the document I want. Awesome answer, thank you so much @neil-lunn